# Navigator expands BottomSheet to full-screen

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am experiencing a problem using `Navigator` within a BottomSheet.

Using Navigator expands the BottomSheet to full screen, while removing it adjusts its height according to the content.

In my case, the Navigator is needed to be able to push to a later view within the BottomSheet.

The desired behaviour would be dynamic height according to content and not full-screen expansion.

Code example:

```
 await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  isDismissible: true,
  useSafeArea: true,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: blocContext,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (context) => MaterialPageRoute<ModalRoute>(
        fullscreenDialog: false,
        builder: (context) => Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.loose,
            children: [
              CustomScrollView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                slivers: [
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverList.separated(
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 30,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return gapH20;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Can you try wrapping it in an IntrinsicHeight widget?

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Container` will cover the full space. You can wrap with  another `Align` widget.

```dart
return Navigator(
  onGenerateRoute: (context) => MaterialPageRoute<ModalRoute>(
    fullscreenDialog: false,
    builder: (context) => Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //this
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
```

More about [layout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints).

Also if you don't need Navigator you can use  `BottomSheet`, `DisplayFeatureSubScreen`,`DraggableScrollableSheet`,

```dart
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return DisplayFeatureSubScreen(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.loose,
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, `Align` works fine if it is inside the Navigator :
Navigator -> Align -> Container 

but it does not seem to work if used in cases such as:
Align -> Container -> Navigator -> Align -> Container,
in this case the First Container expands to full screen.

The result I would like to achieve is to have the Navigator's parent Container fit into its subtree.